# Apache Beam Python SDK ReadFromKafka does not receive data

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying out a simple example of reading data off a Kafka topic into Apache Beam. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    _ = (
        pipeline
        | 'Read from Kafka' >> ReadFromKafka(
            consumer_config={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:29092'},
            topics=['test'])
        | 'Print' >> beam.Map(print))
```

Using the above Beam pipeline snippet, I don't see any messages coming in. Kafka is running locally in a docker container, and I'm able to use `kafkacat` from the host (outside the container) to publish and subscribe to messages. So, I guess there are no issues on that front.

It appears that Beam is able to connect to Kafka and get notified of new messages, as I see the offset changes in the Beam logs as I publish data from `kafkacat`:

```
INFO:root:severity: INFO
timestamp {
  seconds: 1612886861
  nanos: 534000000
}
message: "[Consumer clientId=consumer-Reader-0_offset_consumer_1692125327_none-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1692125327_none] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition test-0"
log_location: "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState"
thread: "22"

INFO:root:severity: INFO
timestamp {
  seconds: 1612886861
  nanos: 537000000
}
message: "[Consumer clientId=consumer-Reader-0_offset_consumer_1692125327_none-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1692125327_none] Resetting offset for partition test-0 to offset 29."
log_location: "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState"
thread: "22"
```

This is how I'm publishing data using `kafkacat`:

```
$ kafkacat -P -b localhost:29092 -t test -K:
1:foo
1:bar
```

and I can confirm that its being received, again using `kafkacat`:

```
$ kafkacat -C -b localhost:29092 -t test -f 'Key: %k Value: %s\n'
Key: 1 Value: foo
Key: 1 Value: bar
```

But despite this, I don't see the actual message being printed by Beam as I expected. Any pointers to what's missing here are appreciated. I'm suspecting this could be a decoding issue on the Beam pipeline side, but could be incorrect.

**Edit (17 Mar 2021):**

After following this issue with the Beam Python Kafka connector developers, the underlying reason why Python `ReadFromKafka` is not behaving as expected is that the portable Flink runner cannot execute unbounded Splittable DoFns (SDFs) as it only supports self-checkpoints. Portable streaming Flink doesn't issue checkpoint requests to the SDK regularly. That's why all Kafka records are buffered at the first `ReadFromKafka` stage. The Jira tracking this issue is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-11991. Additionally, there is another Jira that is tracking the feature request to support this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-11998. Hope this helps!

Comment: LocalRunner also suffers from this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I was having similar issues. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? I'm facing the same issue; I'm publishing data to kafka and trying to read those data from beam using portable flink runner but it's not consuming those data directly